# Using .where condition for results greater than an integer

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Trying to do something pretty straightforward in a Rails controller. Right now, I am showing a user all results matching their `user_id` from a Scoreboard table.

I now want to adjust that to show results from their `user_id` but also only `scores` greater than the integer 0. So I changed my controller to:

```
def index
    @scoreboards = Scoreboard.where(user_id: current_user.id, "score >= 0").order(score: :desc)
end
```

This receives a syntax error, so my comparison in the `.where` is probably wrong. How should I add this second condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to avoid putting these kind of database operations directly in the controller, because the model is the more appropriate place.  I'd write three scopes in the model:

```
class Scoreboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  scope :for_user_id, ->(user_id) { where(user_id: user_id) }
  scope :with_scores, -> { where('score > 0') }
  scope :by_descending_score, -> { order(score: :desc) }
  #...
end
```

...then in the controller, you'd merely write this:

```
Scoreboard.for_user_id(current_user.id).with_scores.by_descending_score
```

This keeps your controller thinner (and more readable) while potentially supporting re-use of these lookups in the most atomic fashion and keeping the database logic wholly contained in the model.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
@scoreboards = Scoreboard.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  .where("category >= 0").order(score: :desc)
```

Comment: This works. For my purpose, I just adjusted the second `.where` to `.where("score > 0")` so it removes those 0 values, and it's working now. Thanks.